# Display Float 6 decimal places with 2 decimal place rounder

Tags: c, rounding, scanf

I want 217.665042 to be rounded to 217.670000. 
Print the rounded numbers to six decimal places.

How do I proceed?

Comment: What about `"%.2f0000"` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 0.01 * floor(x * 100.0 + 0.5);
```

Will round it to `217.669998` bacause the precision of float is far from being able to store `217.670000`.

If you want to just print it, you can use:

```
printf("%.2f0000", x);
```

But keep in mind, that your variable will not be able to store the exact number in case you want to do further calculations with it.